# Recursive function in OCaml

Tags: list, recursion, graph, ocaml

I have this portion of code that finds the next node in a graph using this format :

> current node->(operator, cost, name of next node) list

:

```
let opPoss =(function
      "A" -> [('h',4,"B");('b',10,"C")]
    | "B" -> [('b',2,"C");('h',4,"D")]
    | "C" -> [('b',6,"F")]
    | "D" -> [('b',2,"C")]
```

and this one that finds the weight of each node:

```
let  hEtat = (function
    "A" -> 8
  | "B" -> 3
  | "C" -> 2
  | "D" -> 5
  |  _ -> 0 );;
```

I have to implement a function that returns a list of next node for every node under this format:

> (name  of node, cost, weight)

, so I tried this:

```
let creerLesFils etat g opPoss hEtat=
  let liste = opPoss etat in let rec creer liste g opPoss hEtat= match liste with
        []->[] 
      |(a, b, c)::t->(c, b, hEtat c)::creer t g opPoss hEtat;;
```

but it doesn't work, it shows me this:

> ;; Line 4, characters 45-47: Error: Syntax error

How can I properly implement the recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax error is that you have `let rec` with no following `in`.

In essence, you define a local function named `creer` but you never use the definition for anything.

You might try adding something like this at the end of your code:

```
in
creer liste g opPoss hEtat
```

(This was difficult to answer because the code isn't formatted readably. You can use an automatic indentation tool, or indent manually.)